# Extracting enum from stream C++

Tags: c++, enums

I have an `enum` which looks like this:

```
enum types
  {
    none,
    fire,
    water,
    ....
  };
```

and then

```
char buffer[4096];
cin >> buffer;

if (strcmp(buffer, "fire") == 0)
  type = fire;
... and so on
```

My question is, is there any better and easier way to convert from string to enum type?

P.S - my knowledge currently is at OOP.

Comment: that will only return true if your string is exactly "fire". Is that what you want?

Comment: building and using an `std::map<std::string, types>` might be the best option